# Replace comma with newline following with just a command and space

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, csv, tr

I have a list like so.

```
blue-image1.jpg,
blue-image2.jpg,
blue-image3.jpg
red-image1.jpg,
red-image2.jpg,
red-image3.jpg
```

It's was originally a csv format but I added newlines because they needed a prefix at first. Now I need to put them together again so it becomes like this.

```
blue-image1.jpg,blue-image2.jpg,blue-image3.jpg
red-image1.jpg,red-image2.jpg,red-image3.jpg
```

I tried `cat list.txt | tr ',\n' ','` and `cat list.txt | sed 's/,\n/,/g'`

but neither seem to work properly.

Comment: Switch `sed` for `perl`: `perl -pe 's/,\n/,/' list.txt`. Too bad you didn't come back after posting this question, to accept one of the numerous good answers below.

Answer (score 4):

Just simple as easy with:

```
$ sed -z 's/,\n/,/g' infile
blue-image1.jpg,blue-image2.jpg,blue-image3.jpg
red-image1.jpg,red-image2.jpg,red-image3.jpg
```

The `-z` switch sets the input record separator to `NUL`, thus avoiding issues with `\n`. See `man sed`:

> -z, --null-data
>   separate lines by NUL characters

Answer (score 3):

I'll concede that this next answer is technically less cpu efficient than just a single call to `sed`, but I'm adding it to the mix because it's much more easy to remember, write, read, understand, and modify than the others:

```
cat list.txt | tr ',\n' '#@' | sed 's/#@/,/g;s/@/\n/g'
```

Comment: @user1404316 This will work when assuming no other _comma_ can occur in lines other than only at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same as **39. Append a line to the next if it ends with a backslash "\".** from Peteris Krumins' [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/) but with a comma in place of a backslash as the continuation character i.e.

```
sed -e :a -e '/,$/N; s/,\n/,/; ta' list.txt
blue-image1.jpg,blue-image2.jpg,blue-image3.jpg
red-image1.jpg,red-image2.jpg,red-image3.jpg
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what was asked! You may want to reproduce the excellent explanation here.

Answer (score 1):

`cat list.txt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/,\n/,/g'`

output:

```
blue-image1.jpg,blue-image2.jpg,blue-image3.jpg
red-image1.jpg,red-image2.jpg,red-image3.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g' yourfile
```

Comment: This is certainly a step in the right directions, but it produces just one line of text, while the desired output has all the the blue images on one line, and all the red-images on the next.

Answer (score 0):

I have below one liner to achieve the same.As tested it worked fine

inputfile

```
blue-image1.jpg,
blue-image2.jpg,
blue-image3.jpg
red-image1.jpg,
red-image2.jpg,
red-image3.jpg
```

command

```
sed -n '/^blue/p' inputfile | perl -pne "s/\n//g";echo ""; sed -n '/red/p' p.txt  | perl -pne "s/\n//g"
```

output

```
blue-image1.jpg,blue-image2.jpg,blue-image3.jpg
red-image1.jpg,red-image2.jpg,red-image3.jpg
```

Comment: It does give the desired output! Being a sequence of three independent commands, calling it a one-liner is a bit of a stretch, though. Please note that in one instance you call the input file `inputfile`, while on the second `sed` call it becomes `p.txt` (the input file is `list.txt` in the OP).

Comment: I suggest a simpler `perl -pe 's/,\n/,/' list.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
perl -lape '$\=/,/?"":"\n"' list.txt
```

**Explanation:**

Sets the output record separator `$\` to the empty string `""` if a line contains a comma; resets it to `\n` otherwise (the output record separator is what separates lines one from the other in the output; on Unix, it's normally a newline). Equivalent to the longer and easier to read:

```
perl -lape '(/,/) ? ($\="") : ($\="\n")' list.txt
```

or, similarly:

```
perl -lape 'if (/,/) {$\=""} else {$\="\n"}' list.txt
```

**Comments:**

The reason `sed`  doesn't do what the OP expected is that it strips the record separator before working on the line, and puts it back afterwards. The record separator being `"\n"` by default, no `"\n"` is found for the substitution. I chose `perl` because I know the record separator is exposed as a special variable that can be explicitly manipulated.

My solution is based on the posted input sample and desired output. I don't think it answers the question in the title: *Replace comma with newline following with just a command and space*. I read it many times but those words just don't form a meaningful sequence to me.

**Edit - easier solution:**

```
perl -pe 's/,\n/,/' list.txt
```

This is what I suggested in the comments and I thought I'd also add it to the answer. While it's short and immediate, what's the fun of using `perl` if you can't show off some little-known special variable and obscure syntax? `;-P`

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably get down-votes for this, because it isn't pretty but I must mention what I would do in real life :)

What *you* should do is use the answer provided by simlev using sed with `-z`.

```
sed -z 's/,\n/,/g' list.txt
```

Given the following above list in a file named temp.txt

---

Option: Use vi or vim.
Open the file, then type the following:

```
vim temp.txt
:%s/,\n/,/
:x
```

Then later do yourself a favor and run `vimtutor`.

---

Option:A similar type of regex search&replace can be done with NotePad++

Find what: `,\n`
Replace with: `,`
Search type `regex`

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to read the data as a CSV file with fields that are separated by a comma+newline field separator, and then outputting them using the ordinary field separator for CSV files:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --ifs ',\n' cat file
blue-image1.jpg,blue-image2.jpg,blue-image3.jpg
red-image1.jpg,red-image2.jpg,red-image3.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use paste command:

```
paste -s -d " " list.txt | sed -e 's/[a-z]\ /g\n/g'
```

blue-image1.jpg, blue-image2.jpg, blue-image3.jpg
red-image1.jpg, red-image2.jpg, red-image3.jpg